# Compute and apply gradients 'on gpu' on variables shared across 4 gpus

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, multi-gpu

Consider the network in the [cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) example in tensorflow. Note while creating the towers I don't force the variable creation on the cpu like in the inception example. Now I have to apply a similar training approach to a Wasserstien GAN network. So you have two networks, Generator and Discriminator which you train simultaneously, but you run training operation for the discriminator network multiple times per example. These added steps per example lead to an n-fold training time. I'm trying to approximate this approach, I want to apply the calculated gradients on the gpus itself to the each individual split batch multiple times and get a cumulative gradient, then on the cpu I average these cumulative gradients and apply them to the shared variables. I'm not sure if it can work. Need some insight.

Thanks